# CUDA shared memory broadcast and __syncthreads behavior

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I am experiencing a strange issue, well at least to me it looks strange, and I was hoping someone might be able to shed some light on it. I have a CUDA kernel which relies on shared memory for fast local accesses. To the limits of my knowledge, if all the threads within a half-warp access the same shared memory bank then the value will be broadcast to the threads in the warp. Also, access from multiple warps to the same bank do not cause bank conflicts, they will just be serialized. Keeping this in mind, I have created a small kernel to test this out (after encountering issues in my original kernel). Here's the snippet:

```
#define NUM_VALUES 16
#define NUM_LOOPS  1024

__global__ void shared_memory_test(float *output)
{
    // Create some shared memory
    __shared__ int dm_delays[NUM_VALUES];

    // Loop over NUM_LOOPS
    float accumulator = 0;
    for(unsigned c = 0; c < NUM_LOOPS; c++)
    {
        // Force shared memory update
        for(int d = threadIdx.x; d < NUM_VALUES; d++)
            dm_delays[d] = c * d;

        // __syncthreads();
        for(int d = 0; d < NUM_VALUES; d++)
            accumulator += dm_delays[d];
}

    // Store accumulated value to global memory
    for(unsigned d = 0; d < NUM_VALUES; d++)
        output[d] = accumulator;
}
```

I've run this with a block dimension of 16 (half a warp, not terribly efficient but it's just for testing purposes). All the threads should be addressing the same shared memory bank, so there should be no conflicts. However, the opposite seems to be true. I'm using Parallel Nsight on Visual Studio 2010 for this testing.

What is even more mysterious to me is the fact that if I uncomment the `__syncthreads` call in the outer loop then the number of bank conflicts increases dramatically.

Just some number to give you an idea (this is for a grid containing one block with 16 threads, so a single half-warp, `NUM_VALUES` = 16, `NUM_LOOPS` = 1024):

- without `__syncthreads`: 4 bank conflicts
- with `__syncthreads`   : 4,096 bank conflicts

I'm running this on a GTX 670, set at compute_capability 3.0

Thank you in advance

UPDATE: It was pointed out that without `__syncthreads` the `NUM_LOOPS` reads in the outer loop were being optimized away by the compiler since the values of `dm_delays` never change. Now I get a constant 4,096 bank conflicts in both cases, which still doesn't play well with the broadcast behavior for shared memory.

Comment: Some corrections: access to the same *address* is broadcast (assuming a newer device), but access to the same *bank* (assuming the address is not identical across threads) is serialized, and this serialization is the *defined* effect of a bank conflict. So to say access to a shared memory location results in serialization but is not a bank conflict doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yes you're right. The access in the code snippet should all be to the same shared memory address across the threadblock (all the threads should be accessing dm_delays[d] at the same time, and there are only 16 floating point values allocated to dm_delays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the value of `dm_delays` does not change, this may be a case where the compiler optimizes away the 1024 reads to shared memory if the `__syncthreads` is not present. With the `__syncthreads` there, it may assume that the value could be changed by another thread, and so it reads the value over and over again.

Comment: Valid point. I've updated the outer loop to change the value of dm_delays in each iteration. Now I get a constant 4,096 bank conflicts with and without `__syncthreads`.

Comment: I don't think it can optimize away the reads, but it can reduce the reads to a single pass of the inner loop, then multiply that value by NUM_LOOPS (or bring each of the 16 shared memory values into registers which would have the same effect). Probably that is what was meant in the answer.   You should also be able to eliminate this effect by using the `volatile` keyword in front of the shared memory variable `dm_delays`.  So @lessju could you accept this answer if you're satisfied with it.

Comment: Yeah, forgot all about volatile, right again. Howvever I'm still uncertain as to why I'm getting bank conflicts with a single half warp with all the threads accessing the same shared memory location at each iteration (if I force the inner loop to use a specific shared memory location for all the iterations, say the 2nd location, I still get conflicts, unless I use the 0th location, in which case I don't). This is a partial answer to the original question.

Comment: `volatile` seems to be doing the trick, though I'm not sure exactly how that's avoiding the conflicts. I'll do some further research and testing. Thank you both for your help